# Steam OpenID preventing me logging into existing Stack Exchange account

Tags: support, login, user-accounts, openid, stack-exchange-openid

I have a Stack Exchange account, associated with my Gmail login. For some reason, however, I can't seem to login any more, on this browser. Every time I click on "Join this community", I keep seeing a page that says "Confirm new Account... using a login from Steam".

It's really annoying, I want to use my proper account, with associated rep, etc.

Strangely enough I somehow managed to log into meta.stackexchange.com with the proper account, and I can see my associated Stack Exchange accounts, but when I click on the various links, I go to the site but it doesn't recognize my account.

I would happily logout of my Steam OpenID session or whatever, but for the life of me cannot figure out how.

I've tried clearing cookies and local storage on *stackexchange.com and *steamcommunity.com, but it hasn't helped.

My meta.stackexchange.com account is https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/234935/retnuh
and my normal stackexchange account is https://stackoverflow.com/users/1059650/

This has been going on for quite some time. Any advice on how to reset things such that I can log in with my Gmail account?

Comment: You would need to clear cookies for stackauth.com, not a site domain. Also, have you tried just clicking on the Stack Exchange icon next to that button in the top bar (on a site where it's identifying you as a Steam account) and selecting the "log out" link there?

Comment: Sorry for slow reply - just back to computer in strange situation.  I'm not logged in on the sites showing Steam, so there is no "log out" button.  Trying cookies for "stackauth.com" now.

Comment: I didn't find anything under 'stackauth.com', but I did go and re-clear all the cookies from *.stackexchange.com, as well as stackoverflow.com and superuser.com.  That final clearance, and then reloading the page, seems to have done the trick.  Thanks for sending me down the right path!